# How to compare string in swift4

Tags: swift, string, comparison

i wanna solve below error

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: you are trying to compare array with string.
localMsg.first == myCheck, would be right

Comment: paste code not images.

Comment: `localMsg` is not string there, it's Array of Any... @АлександрКолесник, localMsg.first is not string BTW.

Comment: Yes Guys Thank you so much i am getting.....

Comment: if (String(localMsg) == mycheck) {
         NSLog("True")
    }else{
         NSLog("False")
    }
try this

Comment: @TusharSharma okay i remove bugy answer and upvote and correct which one is true answer.. now can you remove downvote from my question...because of these question my account would get blocked please do something

Comment: @BhaumikJoshi I did't down vote your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error states you cannot compare a `String` (`mycheck`) with an array of `Any` (`localMsg`), you must compare the string directly with something like

```
if let localMsg = oDict_Fail["message"] as? String, localMsg == mycheck {
    NSLog("True")
} else {
    NSLog("False")
}
```

Here we first try to access the `oDict_Fail` dictionary with the key `message`, if it exists try to cast it as a `String` and if it is successful only then do the comparison, if any of this fails the `else` branch will be executed.

You can read more about *optional binding* [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309).

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP's solution is still buggy.

Comment: Ohhh... is it true...!!! @lee okay np... ll find another proper way and update my answer soon... Thank you

Comment: @LeeFastenau okay i remove bugy answer and upvote and correct which one is true answer.. now can you remove downvote from my question...because of these question my account would get blocked please do something

Comment: @Marco Boschi okay i remove bugy answer and upvote and correct which one is true answer.. now can you remove downvote from my question...because of these question my account would get blocked please do something

Comment: Those downvotes were not given because there were some incorrect answers but because your question does not respect the standards for SO, as you can see in the comment on your question you should paste the code as text and not an image, also you should explain more what exactly is that you want.